# Concatenate cstrings c++

Tags: c++, concatenation, cstring

When I run this, I get no errors, but the string does not get concatenated. Could someone tell me what I'm getting wrong here.

```
char *con(const char str[], int n) {
    char * t = new char[60];
    int l = strlen(str);
    t[l] = '\0';
    if (n <= 0) {
        return t;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            strcat(t, str);
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

If I try and take out the:

```
int l = strlen(str);
t[l] = '\0';
```

Then the program crashes.

Comment: There's a reason [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) was invented.

Comment: What is `s`? I don't see it defined anywhere. Is it null-terminated?

Comment: sorry fixed the s, forgot the tr

Comment: Really, do yourself a favor and either 1) replace the C++ tag with the C tag, or 2) use `std::string` and enjoy writing C++

Comment: What does the `n` parameter specify?

Comment: there is not one reason ..your code is broken...

Comment: @Antonijn n is the number of times the string should be concatenated

Comment: the `60` in your code seems a bit arbitrary, wouldn't it be better to calculate the buffer `t` with the help of `n` and `strlen(str)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start with an empty string.

Replace:

```
int l = strlen(str);
t[l] = '\0';
```

With:

```
t[0] = '\0';
```

Now `str` will be concatenated `n` times in `t`.

The original code was leaving the first `l-1` chars in `t` uninitialized.

Comment: hmm that didnt fix it, the program returns nothing if I call ("hi",5)